# Detecting a color when it appears on screen

Tags: c#

I wanted to make a color detection program to display a message box when a certain color is found

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace evade
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SearchPixel("#00042");

        }

        private bool SearchPixel(string hexcode)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

            Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);

            while (true)
            {

                for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                    {
                        Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);


                        if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Found!");
                            return true;

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }



                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

So that's my code. And the color is #00042 this one (html) I'm running the detection on a while loop so when the desired color appears on screen it displays a little message box but It does not work.

Comment: I think your color code is wrong. https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/000042 You need 4 zeros ie: 6 digits for the RGB code

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. It does not work still though

Comment: I think you should put `CopyFromScreen` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: `Bitmap.GetPixel` is very slow method. Use [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Found!");
    return true;

}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Which returns true if the color is found, but at the same time returns false as soon as a color does not match.

What happens if the very first pixel is not a match?  Then you return false without ever checking the rest of the pixels!

Instead, you need to return false after the for loops have exited:

```
for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
    {
        Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Found!");
            return true;

        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Also, get rid of that `while(true)` loop as it's not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Information! Also, I still think I should keep the while since I want to keep constantly checking after I click the button.

Comment: If you keep the while loop called from your button click handler, your app will become un-responsive as you'll tie up the main UI thread and it won't be able to respond to user interaction or re-paint itself.  Besides, with the `return` statements in there, the while loop gets exited; thus it is doing nothing for you.  If you want to periodically check, turn on a Timer control from your Button handler and then check for the color from within the Tick() event.  Or create another thread and check from there...